# Azure Devops dependency in backlog

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is it possible in Azure Devops to identify in a backlog when the Stack rank order conflicts with the predecessor / successor configured?

I.e.

A (predecessor) --> B (successor)

**Backlog 1**

1. A
2. B

OK

**Backlog 2**

1. B
2. A

Display these lines in red or some identification since the order of topics conflicts.

n.b. it requires to be in the backlog, since the prioritizing by utilizing drag&drops happens in this screen, not in a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the backlog view doesn't highlight dependencies that are out of order based on their relationships. [You can see this in a Delivery Plan though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-187-update#dependency-tracking):

[image: Delivery Plan highlighting dependency sequencing issues.]

[image: Dependency highlighted in the card view.]

I'm also not aware of an extension that adds this visualization to the backlog view.